# ODBC ARD and APD management on SQLExecDirect and SQLExecute

Tags: odbc

I got the following code:

```
SQLRETURN ret; 
SQLHSTMT stmt, stmt2;
SQLHDESC Ard, Apd;
/* Alloc code here */
SQLExecDirect(stmt, query, SQL_NTS);
SQLExecDirect(stmt2, query2, SQL_NTS);
/* Binding Column in stmt */
SQLGetStmtAttr(stmt, SQL_ATTR_APP_ROW_DESC, &Ard, 0, NULL);
SQLGetStmtAttr(stmt2, SQL_ATTR_APP_PARAM_DESC, &Apd, 0, NULL);
SQLCopyDesc(Ard, Apd);
/* Do stuff to copy into stmt2 table stmt table */
SQLExecDirect(stmt, query3, SQL_NTS); //select another table
/* Do I need here to rebind the APD on the ARD with SQLCopyDesc()*/
```

And I don't understand what is happening to the ARD of `stmt` after `SQLExecDirect` the second time.

Do the binded columns are unbinded from the Statement? Or the binded column stay binded?

**More simply, does `SQLExecDirect` or `SQLExecute` reset the ARD, APD, IPD, IRD of the Statement?**

And what happend if another statement is linked with one of this Descriptor with `SQLSetStmtAttr`?

Comment: Perhaps [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/descriptor-transitions?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) answers you?

Comment: @TallTed Do you understand like me that the binded parameter or column stay  binded? This mean illegal binding might occurs?  Or the binding are cleaned? (it is missing information about the content of the binding) Is it driver dependent or Standardized?